# Change Icon of *.dll Back To Original

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, file-extension, dll

My idiotic little brother opened a *.dll file with notepad, now it's got that NotePad icon on it. It's a real mess because now I can never distinguish between *.dlls and text files. How do I change the icon of all *.dll files back to the original?

[image: DLL or Text]

P.S Did I mention my brother's a stupid idiotic ape? >:(

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Windows 7:

Go to the following web page and download the registry file for .dll then double click and say yes to add info to registry. You may or may not need to reboot.

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html

Answer (score -2):

I look at the information you provided and do not believe this is the right way to get you registry files back to normal.  I would suggest if its just the file extensions then its advisable to you information providing you operating system, plus to look up how to recover you files from a previous state is a better resolution to the question asked.

Comment: Your answer is mostly run-on sentences that are very hard to interpret into a usable shape.